# How to explain this following code?

Tags: matlab

can you explain me about this following code?? when the size newRowB (1,12), this code cannot work?

```
~any(diff([0;find(newRowB);12+1])>3));
```

thanks before

Comment: I suggest you try the following commands: `help find`, `help diff`, and `help any`.

Answer (score 2):

`diff` calculates the difference between the successive terms of the given input vector.
and

`find` locates elements of array X that are non-zero

Comment: :), help me always yah mr. ihihi

Comment: I have known already mr. about diff and find, thanks you so much